# Unable to cancel the request in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Get method in MVC controller which fetches the data and binds it to a partial view, which is a grid that displays the data.
When a request arrives to fetch 1000 records, it is quickly fetching from DB, but while binding it takes time, meanwhile a loading icon is shown in the UI, and cancel request button.
if the user clicks on cancel request button, UI doesn't show Loading icon anymore.
Upon sending a another request, request doesn't come until a minute or so.
it takes time for second request to arrive at controller method.
even though it was cancelled on click of button.
cancellation token mechanism isn't working.

I need a way to cancel the original request(ajax calls). and let the user be served with second request data

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken)
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        var res = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();

       return await BindResultToPartialView(res, cancellationToken.Token);
    }
```

Comment: _"cancellation token mechanism isn't working."_ - Have you considered finding out why?

Comment: tried it @Fildor but to of no success

Comment: you can do process in other thread and by other api (cancel api) can stop that thread

Comment: @Deepak I guessed so, but did you investigate or did you just give up on it? For example, did you debug if the correct tokensource is being canceld? And without code, we have a hard time making suggestions, of course.

Comment: @Fildor tried to add some code, that replicates in my controller.
i did debug, token state isn't changing. actually, the second request isn't even coming till the controller

Comment: Then my best bet would be, you are cancelling the wrong source. But it's hard to suggest a solution with that little context.

Comment: Beware that the cancellation token does not cancel anything. The cancellation token only informs that a cancellation was requested. It's up to the code that receives it to cancel.